# JavaScript Объекты, доступ к свойству через переменную

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. Из учебника:

> Квадратные скобки также позволяют обратиться к свойству, имя которого
>   хранится в переменной:

```js
    var person = {};
    person['age'] = 25;
    var key = 'age';
    
    alert( person[key] ); // выведет person['age']
```

Я посмотрел данный код и решил попробовать его оптимизировать; т.к. в коде возможно наличие большого кол-ва переменных, подумал, что понятнее будет такая запись:

```js
var person = {};
person['age'] = 25;
var key = person['age'];

alert( person[key] );
```

Но она выдает `undefined`.

**Мои рассуждения:**

**person** - объект; **age** - ключ; **25** - свойство объекта с ключом age;
В своем примере, переменной `key` я пытаюсь присвоить значение свойства объекта `person` с ключом  `age`.

**Мой вопрос:**

Почему моя запись некорректна? В моем понимании они идентичны.

Comment: _person - объект; age - ключ; 25 - свойство объекта с ключом age;_ почему в случае присваивания `person['age'] = 25;` в твоем понимании устанавливается значение, а в случае `var key = person['age'];` ты должен получить ключ? Ведь часть `person['age']` одинакова в обоих случаях

Comment: В первом примере: `alert( person[key] ); // выведет person['age']` ошибочный комментарий. В этом можно убедиться запустив сниппет, который ты добавил в вопрос. alert выведет `25`, что логично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var person = {};
person['age'] = 25;
var key = person['age'];

alert( person[key] );
```

Если элементарно проследить за данные, которые пытается вывести `alert`, то ответ на вопрос выплывает сам по себе:

`alert( person[key] )` -> `alert( person[person['age']] )` -> `alert( person[25] )` -> `undefined`

Comment: Я подозревал это. Я думал, когда мы делаем такую запись `person['age']` мы напрямую обращаемся к свойству объекта через ключ и можем делать манипуляции с ним.  В записи `var key = person['age']` предполагал, переменной `key` мы присваиваем значение ключа, а сам объект при этом не трогаем. Ваш ответ принес ясность. Если других, более развернутых комментариев не будет, я его приму.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, а каким образом можно было прийти к выводу, что если _делаем такую запись person['age'] мы напрямую обращаемся к свойству объекта_, то _В записи var key = person['age'] предполагал, переменной key мы присваиваем значение ключа_??? Почему в одном месте должно было быть свойство объекта, а в другом вдруг появиться ключ?

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за твои комментариии. Поясню еще, я предполагал, что `var key = person['age']` равно`var key = 'age'` и что person[]  в данном случае это всего лишь будет указатель(в каком объекте находится данный ключ). А он оказывается целиком `person['age']` в переменную записывает, когда я предполагал, что он запишет туда только `age`. То, что написал **lexxl**, я такой вариант подозревал, но из-за неимения точного ответа, решил узнать. Когда ты только что-то учишь, далеко не все так очевидно, как возможно с твоей стороны это выглядит; мое предположение кажется мне логичным.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, на самом деле не совсем логично, по крайней мере вот эта часть _`var key = person['age']` равно `var key = 'age'`_

Answer (score 0):

```js
var person = {};
person['age'] = 25;
var key = Object.keys(person);

alert( person[key[0]] ); 

или

var person = {};
person['age'] = 25;
var key = 'age';

alert( person[key] );
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение! Но мой вопрос был именно о возможности другой записи, для данной строки `var key = 'age';` (остальной код остается прежним). Минус не я вам поставил.